# Зачем нужен Bitrix ORM?

Tags: php, база-данных, веб-программирование, битрикс, orm

Читал инфу на [ORM](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=05748&LESSON_PATH=3913.3516.5748), но не понял зачем же все таки нужен Bitrix ORM.
На [ORM в новом ядре](https://hmarketing.ru/blog/bitrix/orm-v-novom-yadre/) написано, что

> Реализация ORM в ядре D7 призвана абстрагировать разработчика от механики работы с таблицами на уровне запросов к БД, введя понятие сущности и поля сущности.

Кроме этого, для чего еще нужен Bitrix ORM при создании сайтов на Bitrix? В чем его практическая польза?

Comment: Основная практическая польза ORM битрикса (а так же битрикса в целом) - позволяет создать качественную ИБД, утилизировать излишки человекочасов и как результат - получить увеличенный бюджет на разработку.

Comment: @Darth 1. как Bitrix ORM позволяет сократить время (приведите практические примеры)? 2. Почему ORM удобнее, чем SQL (опять же приведите практические примеры)?

Comment: 1)  Bitrix ORM позволяет сократить время сугубо на отрицательную величину.
2) Таких причин нет. В теории, ORM должна позволять делать запросы людям, не владеющим sql. Но в объективной реальности человек, не способный написать селект с ORM только сильнее запутается.

Comment: @Darth в таком случае можете на практике показать, в чем преимущества Bitrix ORM? Ваш первый комментарий не ясен.

Comment: Поясню по русски) Обычно такие технологии навязываются менеджерами (в сговоре с техлидом или наоборт - техлидом, через менеджера), чтобы искуственно увеличить сложность проекта в глазах бизнес-заказчиков и получить с последних побольше денежек. Вот его основная практическая польза - эта штука приносит финансы в команду разработки в условиях, когда проект слишком простой, чтобы получить за его нормальную реализацию достаточное количество денег.

Comment: @Darth если думать про ORM как инструмент для написания SQL запросов, когда сам с ним не дружишь, то примерно так и происходит. В остальном написанное - чушь.

Comment: @teran а что еще (**см. вопрос**) дает ORM, кроме написания sql запросов?

Comment: абстракцию над диалектом БД мб? Событийную модель для "моделей", механизмы "поведений", геттеры/сеттеры, инструменты для валидации состояний, сохранений, прочих обработок ошибок? И даже лейзи лоад, в адекватных руках может быть удобен порой. Любой орм это инструмент для упрощения CRUD, который явно сделает работу с БД более надежной, чем просто когда ее напишет вася на коленке. Другой вопрос в том, что разработчик должен знать и понимать, во что выливается использование орм для субд, в какие именно запросы выливается подтягивание отношений, ленивая загрузка, какие поля выбираются и т.п.

Comment: в общем чтобы эффективно использовать любой ОРМ, вы во первых должны уметь эффективно использовать сам SQL, 2) знать какие запросы строит ваш орм, и в целом их логгировать во время разработки чтобы понимать что происходит под капотом

Comment: https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition. Пример того, как далеко можно зайти, намазывая слои абстракций